# WPF subclass Control without adding logic, just to be able to customize style and template?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I'm searching for a good way to create style-able, reusable controls in WPF. For example, I've got a twitter feed that could look something like this (much simplified):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding tweets}>
   <ItemsControl.DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate TargetType="tweet">
         <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding user.image}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

To make this a reusable control, I could put this in a UserControl. But doing just that would make it impossible to change the way the image part is displayed for example.

So what I find myself doing now is creating a control for the user's image, like this:

```
public class UserImage : Control
{
   // Empty class..
}

<Style TargetType="{x:Type UserImage}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserImage}">
          <Image Source="{Binding}" />
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>

// The itemscontrol datatemplate now looks like this
<DataTemplate TargetType="tweet">
   <StackPanel>
      <UserImage DataContext="{Binding user.image}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I could do something like this to customize the appearance of the user image:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type UserImage}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserImage}}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserImage}">
          <Ellipse>
             <Ellipse.Fill>
               <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding}">
             </Ellipse.Fill>
          </Ellipse>
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Even though this works, it does feel a bit inefficient and well ... wrong to have to create an "empty" control for each and every component in the custom control. Is this the way to go, or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: At the end instead of Image you acquired Ellipse. What is the point in creating custom control?

Comment: I need something to put a custom controltemplate onto, so I figured a custom control type could do the trick. But I'm sure there's a better way?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean to acquire but you can use ContentControl, bind Content to img.Source and in ContentTemplate set its look (elipse or anything).

Comment: Inherit from ItemsControl,  that way you can define a default ItemTemplate and styles, but still customize the ItemTemplate anywhere you want.